# Stubbing AWS SDK functions to return exceptions (since SDK v. 2.1)

Tags: exception, amazon-web-services, rspec, amazon-ec2, stub

I am using stubbed responses for AWS SDK calls in my specs and I was always able to stub a function with an exception, and then test if it was appropriately caught, or raised, depending on circumstance. This would be a MWE that was working up until now:

```
let(:aws_creds) { ::Aws::Credentials.new('a', 'b') }
let(:ec2_dummy_client) { ::Aws::EC2::Client.new(credentials: aws_creds, stub_responses: true) }

...

describe 'delete_vpc' do
  it 'raises on non-existent VPC' do
    ec2_dummy_client.stub_responses(:delete_vpc, Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidVpcIDNotFound)
    expect{ec2_dummy_client.delete_vpc(vpc_id: "vpc-a08b44c5")}.to raise_exception(Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidVpcIDNotFound)
  end
end
```

Since upgrading from AWS SDK 2.0 to 2.1, though, I keep getting this (real world) error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect{ec2_dummy_client.delete_vpc(vpc_id: "vpc-a08b44c5")}.to raise_exception(Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidVpcIDNotFound)
   expected Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidVpcIDNotFound, got #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)> with backtrace:
     # ./spec/lib/backends/ec2_backend_spec.rb:691:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/lib/backends/ec2_backend_spec.rb:691:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I realize my approach of assigning an exception in place of a return structure may have been a little naïve to start with, although it worked. What is the correct approach, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out stubbing functions with errors **is** the right apporach but the AWS interface has changed between SDK v. 2.0 and 2.1.

Some errors (not all) are now class `ServiceError`, whose constructor requires two mandatory attributes: `context` and `message`.

For a simple spec, just initializing them is enough, so that the MWE given in the question can be fixed like this:

```
let(:aws_creds) { ::Aws::Credentials.new('a', 'b') }
let(:ec2_dummy_client) { ::Aws::EC2::Client.new(credentials: aws_creds, stub_responses: true) }

...

describe 'delete_vpc' do
  it 'raises on non-existent VPC' do
    ec2_dummy_client.stub_responses(:delete_vpc, Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidVpcIDNotFound.new(Seahorse::Client::RequestContext.new,"VPC does not exist"))
    expect{ec2_dummy_client.delete_vpc(vpc_id: "vpc-a08b44c5")}.to raise_exception(Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidVpcIDNotFound)
  end
end
```

Note the `.new(...)` part in the call to `stub_responses()`.